# How to visualize two foreign keys with one Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hello i have problem with visualize names of two foreigns key. Im develop football `database` on `sql`, here is part of my `relationship diagram`

[image]

And this is my `Select Query`:

```
Select team.Name, comp.Name,comp.Stage,fixDate.Date,news.Description
FROM Fixtures fix
Join Competition comp 
On fix.CompetitionID = comp.ID
Join FixtureDate fixDate
On fix.FixtureDateID=fixDate.ID
Join News news
On news.ID = fix.NewsId
Join Teams team
On fix.AwayTeamID = team.ID;
```

The problem is that i **don`t** know how to visualize homeTeam name and awayTeam name. I try with

```
 On fix.AwayTeamID = team.ID AND fix.HomeTeamID = team.ID
```

but output is empty response..

Here is the output with only one team name

[image]

but i want to show and his opponent away team.
Thanks in advice!

Comment: YOu need to join to the team table twice, once for each FK

Comment: yea thanks for response it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two joins with table aliases for this.

```
Select team1.Name, team2.Name, comp.Name, comp.Stage, fixDate.Date, news.Description
FROM Fixtures fix
Join Competition comp 
On fix.CompetitionID = comp.ID
Join FixtureDate fixDate
On fix.FixtureDateID=fixDate.ID
Join News news
On news.ID = fix.NewsId
Join Teams team1
On fix.HomeTeamID = team1.ID
Join Teams team2
On fix.AwayTeamID = team2.ID;
```